# How to fix libXft.so.2: cannot open shared object file when simulating hardware in Quartus 20.1 running on Pop_OS 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, quartus, intel-fpga

I have recently moved to Linux and am getting used to the OS, I managed to install and run Quartus 20.1 Lite and I was testing it out with an old working project. When I opened my waveform and ran the simulation I get

> root/intelFPGA_lite/20.1/modelsim_ase/linuxaloem//vish: error while loading shared libraries: libXft.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have libXft.so.2 installed as I was able to find it using locate in the terminal. Is there something I'm missing? does the file need to be in the file listed above or do I need to play with permissions somehow?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a common problem with using the "free" modelsim on modern linux distribution.
Modelsim is 32b and is not very well packaged so it doesn't fetch its dependencies.

now, the solution is to install a lot of 32b packages.

```bash
    sudo apt-get install libxft2 libxft2:i386 lib32ncurses5
    sudo apt install libxext6
    sudo apt install libxext6:i386
    sudo apt install lib32ncurses6
```

ref: https://yoloh3.github.io/linux/2016/12/24/install-modelsim-in-linux/

Comment: this works with one tweak, lib32ncurses5 has been updated and now requires the use of lib32ncurses6. Once those were run it worked like it should. Thanks!